# How can I get an int next to a word using scanf?

Tags: scanf

How can I extract an int contained in a string like `att249` or `berlin32` using **sscanf** ?

I tried

```ml
"%s%d"
```

Which doesn't work because the `%s` scan doesn't stop on the `2`

Answer (score 0):

After asking on the OCaml discord, I got the answer on how to achieve this :

```ml
"%[^0-9]%d"
```

Which works well because `%[^0-9]` scan until it encounters a digit.

Being a complete beginner in scanf, I don't know if it's the best way to achieve it though.